# Default file on a cck field

Tags: 6, entities, files

I want to have a .pdf application form attached by default as a cck field on a custom content type called vacancies, so that every new vacancy created has the pdf file attached without the user having to upload it manually. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to show a default PDF file attachment with custom type nodes. And need to upload some specific to replace the default one via CCK file field.

CCK file field cannot be associated with some default file easily.

The best approach can be...

- Place the default document in file system
- Edit `content-type.tpl.php` and check CCK field (e.g. `$node->field_name`) for file upload
- Print the link of uploaded file if exists Else print the link to default file

Comment: I suppose it will be the same for views, modifying the template file, will it not? Thanks for that.